# How to debug a Angular 4 unit tests using Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a Angular 4 / Material project and are using Visual Studio Code. The project is set up using angular/cli

I have started to write some unit tests using Karma and Jasmin. The setup is all done by angular/cli.

Now I would like to debug my tests.

Running "ng test" gives a few errors.  Trying to debug those errors by setting a breakpoint in the code,, gives no result.

Using google I have found a lot of suggestion how to configure Karma and VSC,, but none of them have helped me. 
My guess is that this is a version dependent problem.

So based on my setup can anyone help me?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "npm": "^5.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.26",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "npm-check-updates": "^2.12.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.2",
    "tslint": "~5.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.0"
  }
```

**EDIT**

If I publish my configuration files maybe someone can see some problems.

```html
tsconfig.json


{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceRoot": "../src",
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

```html
tsconfig.spec.json


{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

```html
karma.config.js



module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    browsers: ['ChromeDebugging'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeDebugging: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [ '--remote-debugging-port=9333' ]
      }
    },
    
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

```html
launch.json


{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 9333,
            "pathMapping": {
                "/": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "/base/": "${workspaceRoot}/"
              }
            
        },

        {
            "name": "Run jasmine",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
            
            "skipFiles": [
              "node_modules/**/*"
            ],       
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
              "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceRoot}/*"
            }
          },
                {
                    "type": "chrome",
                    "request": "attach",
                    "name": "Attach Karma Chrome",
                    "address": "localhost",
                    "port": 9333,
                    "sourceMaps": true,
                    "trace": "verbose",
                    "pathMapping": {
                        "/": "${workspaceRoot}/",
                        "/base/": "${workspaceRoot}/"
                    }
                }
           
    ]
}
```

Comment: is browser console not good enough? I know you have asked specifically for VSCode debugging help, yet just wanted to know if you have tried debugging via browser consoles?

Comment: I tried,,, but I never found out how to set a breakpoint in source code.

Comment: Let me tell you for chrome, other browsers too have similar ways to debug. When your test executes you will notice a browser window open (assuming you are not running headless). On that browser window you have a debug button. Hit that.. Then on the debug window hit f12 and then on sources tab open you spec file (ts)via "Ctrl+o". Put breakpoint and run tests again(f5). You should be able to hit breakpoints

Comment: Ok,, I have done that before. My problem was the I never could find my source code. No where to put the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a new angular with latest and greatest angular-cli. It worked like a dance,, and then I copied the configuration files to my real project.